# How to work on each two adjacent list items at a time in Elixir?

Tags: list, loops, linked-list, functional-programming, elixir

I want to add a field to each two adjacent items in a list to contain the id of each other, i.e. create a doubly linked list. The reason is that the list is ordered by a particular DB query, and I want to make use of this order in some frontend templates.

In procedural languages this is straightforward with a for loop, where I can change the fields of `myList[index]` and `myList[index + 1]` in the loop body.

I have thought about several ways to do this in Elixir, e.g. `chunk_every`, `zip` the list with itself shifted by 1, or `Enum.with_index` together with `Enum.at`, but so far none has been really satisfactory/efficient.

What would be the idiomatic Elixir way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recurse through the regular linked list and deconstruct the current head and next head. A special case to look for is right before the base case (i.e. an item that doesn't have a "next_id" or similar.

For example if we had a list of maps like:

```
  my_list = [
    %{id: 1, next: nil, previous: nil},
    %{id: 2, next: nil, previous: nil},
    ...
  ]


  def doubly_link([]), do: []

  def doubly_link([head | []]) do
    head = %{head | next: nil}

    [head | doubly_link([])]
  end

  def doubly_link([head | [next_head | tail]]) do
    head = %{head | next: next_head.id}
    next_head = %{next_head | previous: head.id}

    [head | doubly_link([next_head | tail])]
  end
```

Then calling `doubly_link(my_list)` would produce:

```
[
  %{id: 1, previous: nil, next: 2},
  %{id: 2, previous: 1, next: 3},
  ....,
  %{id: n, previous: prior_to_n_id, next: nil}
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution. Using recursion should indeed be natural in FP.

Comment: `doubly_link([next_head] ++ tail)` ⇒ `doubly_link([next_head | tail])`?

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks! Flipping between languages and stream of conscience-d the answer. Editing to improve!

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use [`Enum.with_index/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#with_index/2) twice:

```rb
input = Enum.map(0..4, & %{id: &1})
head = -1
tail = Enum.count(input)

input
|> Enum.with_index(head)
|> Enum.with_index(head + 2)
|> Enum.map(fn
  {{value, ^head}, next} ->
    Map.put(value, :next, next)
  {{value, prev}, ^tail} ->
    Map.put(value, :prev, prev)
  {{value, prev}, next} ->
    value
    |> Map.put(:prev, prev)
    |> Map.put(:next, next)
end)

#⇒ [
#    %{id: 0, next: 1},
#    %{id: 1, next: 2, prev: 0},
#    %{id: 2, next: 3, prev: 1},
#    %{id: 3, next: 4, prev: 2},
#    %{id: 4, prev: 3}
# ]
```